# Opencv - create binary mask with ones inside a polygon(given its vertices)

Tags: opencv

Requirement: Create a binary mask of 640x360 size. Points lying inside a polygon are marked as 1. Otherwise 0.

Input: Vertices of the polygon. The vertices are obtained when a user marks a polygon on an html page.

Is it possible to do so in opencv in an easy way?

I know of one possible solution. http://alienryderflex.com/polygon/. This allows to find whether a point lies inside a polygon given its vertices. But it requires me to run through each pixel to find if they lie inside the polygon, which I feel is a lengthy process.

Comment: How about `fillPoly`? http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/basic_geometric_drawing/basic_geometric_drawing.html

Comment: Don't you mean *polyon* instead of *polynomial*?

Comment: @DanByström: Thanks for pointing it out. Made the correction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to do so in opencv in an easy way?

Yes you want to use the OpenCV [fillPoly](http://void%20fillPoly(Mat&%20img,%20const%20Point**%20pts,%20const%20int*%20npts,%20int%20ncontours,%20const%20Scalar&%20color,%20int%20lineType=8,%20int%20shift=0,%20Point%20offset=Point()%20)) function:

```
void fillPoly(Mat& img, const Point** pts, const int* npts, int ncontours, const Scalar& color, int lineType=8, int shift=0, Point offset=Point() )
```

You can find an example on how to use this [here](http://opencvexamples.blogspot.com/2013/10/basic-drawing-examples.html#.VQE8nKybEXQ) but effectively what fillPoly() does is "fills an area bounded by several polygonal contours. The function can fill complex areas, for example, areas with holes, contours with self-intersections (some of their parts), and so forth."